# EF 6 - duplicate navigation properties with inherited entity

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity

I have a database with several tables and entity framework EDMX model. Let's say I have the following simplified structure.

Table: Person
Column: PersonId (PK)

Table: Parent
Column: PersonId (PK, FK)

Table: Child
Column: PersonId (PK, FK)
Column: ParentId (FK)

[image]

For brevity I removed other columns. PersonId is the primary key in all tables and it is foreign key from Parent and Child tables to Person table. Also Child has a foreign key relationship to Parent through ParentId column.

Also I have configuration in EDMX, so that Parent and Child have BaseType as Person. Now when I do "Update Model from Database..." in Visual Studio, I have some extra navigation properties. Now Parent entity has Childs navigation property to Child table, which is correct because of ParentId foreign key in Child table. However Parent table has also Persons navigation property, which is list of Person entities. I guess this is because Child is derived from Person, but I don't see any reason in this because I already have Childs property to a descendant class (Child).

I think it was working fine some time ago, but now every time I use "Update Model from Database", I have to manually remove redundant association and navigation properties for Parent and Child. Maybe I'm missing some configuration, any help would be appreciated.

Also recently I upgraded EF to version 6, so maybe this caused this issue?
Also this is Database First approach.

Comment: I don't really understand your db structure here. You could do all of this much easier with only 2 tables?

Comment: As I said this is a simplified structure. I have plenty of other columns in Person, Parent and Child tables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were a lot of columns in Person and Parent tables, however there were only two columns in Child table. It turned out that EF treated my Child table as Many-to-Many relationship between Parent and Person.
Basically EF treats any table as many-to-many relationship if it has only two columns and both of them are foreign keys to other tables.
My fix was obvious - I simply added a new column to Child table:

Table: Child
Column: PersonId BIGINT NOT NULL (PK, FK)
Column: ParentId BIGINT NOT NULL (FK)
Column: ChildIdentity BIGINT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL